# accessing image control from codebehind

Tags: .net, imagefield

Compiler Error Message: CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageField'

```
Line 107:    protected void BookListView_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 108:    {
Line 109:        ImageField img = (ImageField)BookListView.FindControlR("Image1");
Line 110:        if (img.ImageUrl == "")
Line 111:            img.ImageUrl = "Snoimage.gif";
```

the control is find but ...

error occured in line 109

FindControlR is an extension to find the control

the control is located in a listview

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Pic_Address") %>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to cast an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.aspx) control to an [ImageField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagefield.aspx) control.

Try modifying your code slightly:

```
Image img = (Image)BookListView.FindControlR("Image1");
```

Comment: i want to access the ImageUrl property of the image control, the problem is i cant access the control.
FindControlR returns control,i want to know how to cast it to imagefield so i can set the ImageUrl in the code behind.

Comment: Your code is already casting the Control to an ImageField. The reason it's throwing the exception is because you're trying to cast the Image control (ASP:Image) to an ImageField (ASP:ImageField). Either modify your casting code or modify the front-end code to use ASP:ImageField.